# Syntax Highlighter for Java in Flex or Actionscript

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a Java syntax highlighter for using in flex. Is there any opensource libraries available for this?

Comment: Don't know whether this may help, but you could have a look at the [moonshine project](http://code.google.com/p/moonshineproject/). It's an open source IDE for Flash/Flex, built with Flex. There must be a syntax highlighter in there you might be able to modify to a Java syntax highlighter.

Comment: There's also [this one](http://code.google.com/p/as3syntaxhighlight/) you might be able to modify. Note that both were written before 'Workers' were introduced, so performance will not be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

### Edited

I recommed [as3syntaxhighlight](https://code.google.com/p/as3syntaxhighlight/). also see a this post [flex-syntax-highligher](http://www.nbilyk.com/blog/1/71/flex-syntax-highlighter)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question: the OP is asking for a Flex syntax highlighting library; this is an Eclipse theme manager plugin.

Comment: @RIAstar is right, I am looking for some flex lib, not any eclipse plugin.